# Finding inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, fourier-transform

I have an expression like this:

$$U(x,p)=e^{-ix(p^2/(2k))}\cdot e^{ix(k(m^2-1)/2)}$$

with

$$U(x,p)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,z)e^{-ipz}dz$$

How do I find $u(x,z)$ I am not sure how to approach this at all?

The first thing to do I think is to make the two statements equal:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,z)e^{-ipz}dz=e^{-ix(p^2/(2k))}\cdot e^{ix(k(m^2-1)/2)}$$

But now I don't know what to do. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you aware of the “inverse Fourier transform”? (As a name of the transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$u(x,z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}U(x,2\pi q)e^{2\pi i q z} dq$$

Note:

Typically
$$F(\omega; \cdot) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t; \cdot)e^{- 2\pi i \omega t} dt $$
and
$$f(t; \cdot) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega; \cdot)e^{2\pi i \omega t} d\omega $$

So I rewrite your $p$ as $p=2\pi q$

Comment: Thank you, it's all clear now :)